# Is it safe to replace a folder with a partition mounted to that folder n Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, symbolic-link, vmware-workstation

I know most programs won't notice the difference, but is it true for e.g. virtualization software like VMware?

I'll give you an example:

1. Let's say my virtual machines are in `C:\_VM\`
2. My `C:` space runs low.
3. I start Windows 7 in safe-mode.
4. Change the name of the folder (to e.g. `C:\_VM_tmp\`).
5. Create new partition and mount it to `C:\_VM\`.
6. Copy contents of `C:\_VM_tmp\` to `C:\_VM\`.
7. Restart.

Would all just work or would I be in trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application in general would not care, unless it tries hard to. Mounting a drive to a directory is transparent to the application, i.e., the app is oblivious to that fact.

Vmplayer or vmware workstation does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your programmes shouldn't care where ever your files are. Unless, that is, Windows 7's way of mounting partitions is *vastly* different from Linux's. I would go ahead with it if I were you.